# How to adopt ꜱᴅ card as Internal storage on Android pie and above on devices without the option in the menu?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, 9.0-pie, internal-sd, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

A well‑known workaround in such case is this *(and as you can see with those command this didn’t worked for me)* :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>adb shell
gts3llte:/ $ sm set-force-adoptable on
gts3llte:/ $ sm list-disks adoptable
disk:179,64
gts3llte:/ $ sm partition disk:179,64 mixed 50
gts3llte:/ $ sm mount private:179,67
gts3llte:/ $ sm list-volumes all
private:179,67 unmountable
private mounted null
public:179,65 mounted 3531-1DC7
emulated mounted null
gts3llte:/ $ reboot

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>
```

But starting with Android Pie, those commands [were moved from vold to `Binder` and as `sm` only affects `vold` some of the commands above are now dummy.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/11c2d380a786d9e304416be98881b90b74ff666d).

This also affects the way to do it with root. Though in my case, now that I did this, going to storage settings systematically crash the settings app.

So how to use sd card as internal storage with newer versions of android ?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible anymore. See: https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/issues/984

Comment: @MorrisonChang even as root ? It rather seems that with the advent of adoptable storage, the functionality is the same but the way to do it different.